# My loop produces the same vaues each time - why?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

my result from foreach loop is

> $a = 12; $a = 12; $a = 12; // some processes // some processes // some processes

I don't see the reason of it.

check.php

```
  $lineGroup = array();
 if ($readfile) {
     while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($readfile))) {
           if (strpos($line, 'function') !== false) {

                 while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($readfile))) {
                         $lineGroup = array($line);                                  
                         break;

                  }
      }
```

checkfunction.php

```
global $lineGroup;
foreach ($lineGroup as $lg) {
    echo $lg;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question??

Comment: kindly share complete code in your question.

Comment: i think you have an array with same values and you want to unique result set? is that right?

Comment: Simply use `array_unique($your_array,SORT_REGULAR);` on your array, before looping

Comment: array_unique is not work...I got same result @Uchiha

Comment: Post your array structure use `var_export($your_array);exit;`

Comment: Array ( ) Array ( ) array ( 0 => ' $a = 12; ', )Array ( [0] => $a = 12; ) Array ( [0] => $a = 12; ) Array ( [0] => $a = 12; ) array ( 0 => ' // some processes ', )Array ( [0] => // some processes ) Array ( [0] => // some processes ) Array ( [0] => // some processes ) @Uchiha

Comment: you need not array(), but array_push().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line as an element to an array.

So, you need not array(), but [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

or in your case,

```
array_push($lineGroup, $line);
```

also, you can use

```
$lineGroup[] = $line;
```